# Opening Google Form Url in Chrome CustomTab is redirecting to Device installed Chrome Browser

Tags: android, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I am opening links like "https://forms.gle/formId" in Android Chrome CustomTabs. But Opening these Urls is redirecting to a Chrome Browser. How can I restrict to Open the redirect Url also in CustomTab itself instead of browser. In **WebView** , this can be handled by overriding **shouldoverrideUrlLoading** method. Below is the piece of code to Open Custom Tabs.

```
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, Uri.parse("https://forms.gle/formId"));
```

Comment: I just ran into this issue myself, and it looks like the only solution is to pass the full redirected URL into the Custom Tab (instead of the shortlink). If you're hardcoding the `forms.gle` URL, you can hardcode the redirected URL instead. And if you're getting the `forms.gle` link at runtime, you can get the redirected URL using a background network call.